# Spring Boot get fields between two dates

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I have this DTO in Spring Boot that reference a collection on MongoDB.

```
@Document(collection = "his")
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class His{

    @Id
    private String internalId;
    private String person;
    private String type;
    private Date date;

}
```

And i want to find all objects that the date is between two dates. I already have this (Only with 2 months of difference):

```
@Override
public ResponseEntity<List<His>> getHisByDate(String dateTo, String dateFrom) {
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    Period diff = Period.between(LocalDate.parse(dateFrom), LocalDate.parse(dateTo));
    if(diff.getYears() == 0 && diff.getMonths() <= 2 && diff.getMonths() >= -2) {

         // Here the query

    } else {

         //Throw Error

    }

    return null;
}
```

How i do that with `Query`?

**SOLUTION:**

```
@Override
public ResponseEntity<List<His>> getPagosByFechaPago(String dateTo, String dateFrom) {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

        Date dateHasta = null, dateDesde = null;
        try {
            dateHasta = formatter.parse(dateTo);
            dateDesde = formatter.parse(dateFrom);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Period diff = Period.between(LocalDate.parse(dateFrom), LocalDate.parse(dateTo));
        if(diff.getYears() == 0 && diff.getMonths() <= 2 && diff.getMonths() >= -2) {
            Query query = new Query();
            query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("date").gte(dateHasta).lt(dateDesde));
            List<His> response = mongoTemplate.find(query, His.class);
            log.info(response.toString());
            return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that

```
public interface HisRepository extends MongoRepository<His, String> {

    @Query("{ date: { $gte: ?0, $lte: ?1 } }")
    List<His> findObjects(Date dateFrom, Date dateTo);

    List<His> findAllByDateGreaterThanEqualAndDateLessThanEqual(Date dateFrom, Date dateTo);

}
```

Please note to the condition of your boundaries: `$gte` or `$gt`, `$lte` or `$lt`.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query-comparison/

Comment: My interface extends from CrudRepository and i can't change it

Comment: You can also build queries based on the method name by using [keywords](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-keywords). [Example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation)